# How do I post from my fan page feed onto my wordpress site?

Tags: wordpress, android-activity, embed, feed, facebook-page

I'm looking to embed the activity feed from my Facebook fan page onto my Wordpress site, like [this example](http://www.lucky-management.com/jordan.php).

I want to utilize a similar box that pulls the feed from my Facebook fan page and posts it to my wordpress site.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you're not technical, so your best bet is a plugin for wordpress. Theres tons available. Here's a list of ten: http://wpapi.com/10-great-wordpress-plugins-for-facebook/